# How to get sansserif font with footmisc package

Tags: fonts, xetex, footmisc

Why does the footmisc package disable my footnote font settings?  I want footnotes in a sans serif font, and have found a way to do this using `\addtokomafont` but I would also like a hanging indent style which is enabled with the package `footmisc`.  They don't seem to play well together.

```
\documentclass[paper=6in:9in,10pt,twoside,pagesize=pdftex,openright]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize\sffamily}
\begin{document}
this is text\footnote{this is the footnote in sans serif font}
\end{document}
```

The block above will produce footnotes with sans serif font.  If you un-comment the `\usepackage` line, the footnote paragraph is formatted more suitably, but the font is no longer a sans serif font.  How can I get the hanging indent formatting and a sans serif font at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `footmisc` includes `\reset@font` in its redefinition of `\@footnotetext` which is equivalent to `\normalfont`. It then issues a `\footnotesize` so you end up with footnote-sized text in whatever the default font family is. If that is serif, you get serif. If it were sans, you would get sans. This is generally what you want: it is not at all usual to want footnote text to be typeset in a different family from the body text.

There are at least two solutions. One uses the facilities already offered by Koma and is definitely the cleaner solution if you don't otherwise need `footmisc`. The other patches the `\@footnotetext` command *after* `footmisc` has redefined it to directly insert the call to the sans family. (You could set this up to use Koma's font commands but if you decide you want serif instead, it would be easier to just remove the patch.)

## Koma Solution

```
\documentclass[paper=6in:9in,10pt,twoside,pagesize=pdftex,openright]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize\sffamily}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{% modified example from page 83
  \makebox[1.5em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}
\begin{document}
  this is text\footnote{this is the footnote in sans serif font but it needs to be a lot longer than it was if the actual effect is to be clearly illustrated}
\end{document}
```

[image: sans hanging footnote]

## Patching `footmisc`

This requires `etoolbox` to do the patching. The console output and/or log file will note whether the patching succeeded or not.

```
\documentclass[paper=6in:9in,10pt,twoside,pagesize=pdftex,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\reset@font}{\reset@font\sffamily}{\typeout{Footnotes patched successfully.}}{\typeout{Footnote patching failed.}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  this is text\footnote{this is the footnote in sans serif font}
\end{document}
```

[image: patched footnotes]

Note that I absolutely do not recommend this from a typographical point of view. I think it looks quite wrong to have footnotes in sans when the body is in serif. (And what should be done with the markers? Should they be sans to match the note or serif to match the text? Or should the same mark be typeset differently in the two places just to confuse people?) However, this site is not concerned with typographical aesthetics.

Comment: I appreciate the answer on LaTex *and* I appreciate the pointer on typographic aesthetics.  I am relatively new to both.  I have seen at least one book that looked quite good with a "light" ss font for the notes, and I am trying to emulate that.  What I am trying to do would probably horrify an experienced person.

Comment: @AgilePro Not necessarily. I know very little. I just know that they tell you not to mix fonts unless you know what you are doing and that even using sans for section titles is already rather dangerous! (I don't know what I'm doing. I do sometimes mix fonts...)

Comment: Excellent.   The Koma only solution is best.  Always better to use fewer packages.   One follow on question if I may:  how do you find the scripts/code in the packages?  Where would I look to find out what a particular package defines and how it does it?

Comment: I use `texdoc <package name>` which usually works eg. `texdoc scrbook` or `texdoc footmisc`. Or I read the documentation online by searching CTAN if that's more convenient e.g. [scrbook](http://ctan.org/pkg/scrbook). I don't know if `texdoc` is specific to TeX Live or whether MiKTeX has it, too.

Comment: @AgilePro I always forget to ping.